# Converting boost multi_array to its native array type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I am writing a class that acts as a go-between for c++ classes and legacy c code.
I have been using boost multi_array's to simplify a lot of the code. This mult_array is declared as such:

```
using Array = boost::multi_array<float,2>
```

However, I have run into a problem where I need to pass my multi_array to a legacy function that has a signature similar to

```
void function(float param[ROWS][COLS]);
```

My multi_array is of size ROWS and COLS, but I do not know of any easy way to convert the mutli_array to an array. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23649263/3962537

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the storage order of `boost::multi_array` is [well defined](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_storage), you can actually call it safely like that:

```
function((float (*)[COLS])array.data());
```

`c_storage_order` is the default, make sure to not use anything else upon construction of the object.